# dynamically added elements are not removing from the form in angular JS

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to remove an input element which was added dynamically into a form.

I am using the below code for this.

```js
 var MyEle =  angular.element(document.getElementById('testID'));
  MyEle.remove();
```

and the input element is added dynamically as below

```html
<ng-form name="TestForm" novalidate">
 <div class="testData">
    <input type="text" name="FirstName1" ng-model="FirstName1" ng-required="true"/>
    <input type="text" id="testID" name="FirstName2" ng-model="FirstName2" ng-required="true"/>
  </div>
</ng-form>
```

The above code is removing the  element but still the form is showing invalid even after entering the data into **First** Input(FirstName1) element.

It seems the removal process is not yet completed. It is not removing from the form. but I am not able to see it on the page.

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do here, but angular was not designed to work like this... You should keep the state of the element in the controller and handle it's visibility on the view with `ng-if` of `ng-hide`

Answer (score 1):

Use ng-if, avoid manipulate the DOM in Controller.

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove validation errors you should remove the element and compile again the form, your code should bes some thing like this, you should also inject `$compile` to your controller

```
 var MyEle =  angular.element(document.getElementById('testID'));
 MyEle.remove();
 var parentElement = document.getElementsByClassName("testData");
 $compile($(parentElement)($scope);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you a more Angular approach to make a dynamic form, check the snippet

```js
// the main (app) module
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

// add a controller
myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.form = [{
    name: "FirstName1",
    required: true,
    type: "text",
    value: "billy"
  }, {
    name: "FirstName2",
    required: true,
    type: "text",
    value: "bolly"
  }];

  $scope.remove = function() {
    $scope.form.pop();
  };

  $scope.add = function() {
    $scope.form.push({
      name: "new_input_"+$scope.form.length,
      required: true,
      type: "text",
      value: "bolly_"+$scope.form.length
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input type="{{input.type}}" ng-repeat="input in form" name="{{input.name}}" ng-model="input.value" ng-required="input.required" />
  <button ng-click="add()">add</button>
  <button ng-click="remove()">remove</button>
</body>
```